# JavaScript Как получить вложенную структуру из списка объектов?

Tags: javascript

Есть список объектов вида:

```
const objects = [
  { type: 'type1', subtype: 'type1-subtype1' },
  { type: 'type1', subtype: 'type1-subtype2' },
  { type: 'type2', subtype: 'type2-subtype1' },
  { type: 'type2', subtype: 'type2-subtype2' },
  { type: 'type2', subtype: 'type2-subtype3' }
]
```

Необходимо получить структуру вида:

```
{
  type1: [ 'type1-subtype1', 'type1-subtype2' ],
  type2: [ 'type2-subtype1', 'type2-subtype2', 'type2-subtype3' ]
}
```

Т.е. ключами должны быть уникальные значения полей *type* исходных объектов, а значениями списки уникальных значений *subtype* объектов с одинаковыми значениями полей *type*.
Получить уникальные значения полей *type* получилось.

```
[...new Set(objects.map(item => item.type))]
```

А вот как добавить остальное?

Comment: Вы что-нибудь слышали о циклах?

Answer (score 1):

```js
const objects = [
  { type: 'type1', subtype: 'type1-subtype1' },
  { type: 'type1', subtype: 'type1-subtype2' },
  { type: 'type2', subtype: 'type2-subtype1' },
  { type: 'type2', subtype: 'type2-subtype2' },
  { type: 'type2', subtype: 'type2-subtype3' }
];

const result = objects.reduce(
  (r, i) => ((r[i.type] || (r[i.type] = [])).push(i.subtype), r), {}
);
console.log(result);
```